# Average output in R

Tags: r

I am replicating a code 50 times and then I want average the output!

The code that is being replicated:

```
output <- gbm.step(data=data.sample, 
                            gbm.x = 2:9,
                            gbm.y = 1,
                          family = "poisson",
                            tree.complexity = 3,
                            learning.rate = 0.0002,
                            bag.fraction = 0.6)
```

I need to figure out what values of the different meta-parameters(tree.complexity, learning.rate and bag.fraction) gives the best model. There is one response variable and 8 predictor variables.

So the output for 1 replication looks like this

```
'fitting final gbm model with a fixed number of  850  trees for  Freq 

mean total deviance = 292.371 
mean residual deviance = 214.589 

estimated cv deviance = 264.341 ; se = 53.483 

training data correlation = 0.568 
cv correlation =  0.565 ; se = 0.053'
```

I want to take the mean of the estimated cv deviance score from the 50 iterations.

I am pretty new to R so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To call a function multiple times, use `replicate`

Comment: Thanks, that worked quite well! - now I only need to know how to mean the output :)

Comment: I don't know what a `gbm` object looks like exactly, which is why I can't help with that. How do you get the deviance, is it something like `output$deviance`? If yes, then if you have `v <- replicate(...)` then try `mean(sapply(v, "[[", "deviance"))`. Just a guess...

Comment: Your help is very appreciated konvas! I can use output$cv.statistics$deviance.mean then it returns the value. But if I type in v$cv.statistics$deviance.mean, it returns NULL. 

what do you mean with "[["?

Comment: You basically have to apply it to each entry of `v` (and not `v` itself), since `v` is a list of `gbm` objects. How about `deviances <- sapply(v, function(x) x$cv.statistics$deviance.mean)`. This should return a vector of deviances. Then the mean is `mean(deviances)`.

Comment: When I type in deviances <- sapply(v, function(x) v$cv.statistics$deviance.mean) it gives me a list with 410 NULL values. :S.

Comment: Note that its `x$cv.statistics$deviance.mean` inside the function (not `v$...`) :)

Comment: If I type `x$cv.statistics$deviance.mean` then it returns this :     `Error in x$cv.statistics : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: Hmm weird.. not sure why this is, as I cannot replicate. Does it work if you do `v[[1]]$cv.statistics$deviance.mean`?

Comment: It returns the same result :( Can I send some data and code to you so you can replicate? :)

Comment: Yes, could you post the output of `dput(data.sample)` ?

Comment: It's probably not all needed, I just have to get an idea, how about `dput(head(data.sample))`

Comment: When u write data sample? you mean dput(head(v)) right?

Comment: I meant the `data.sample` in your code. The data that you use `gbm.step` on.

Comment: It is too long for the comment option, but I will insert in my  question :) And thanks for your patience!

Comment: It does work for me. Let me post all the steps in detail in an answer and you can try to do it on your data, let me know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function `f` that will be run 50 times using `replicate`. Then extract the deviances from each run and take their mean as follows:

```
f <- function(d) {
    output <- gbm.step(data=d, 
        gbm.x = 2:9,
        gbm.y = 1,
        family = "poisson",
        tree.complexity = 3,
        learning.rate = 0.0002,
        bag.fraction = 0.6)
    return(output)
}

# Use simplify = FALSE to get the result in a list, 
# rather than coerced to an array
v <- replicate(50, f(data.sample), simplify = FALSE) 
# Gather all deviance means in v in a vector
deviances <- sapply(v, function(x) x$cv.statistics$deviance.mean)
# Finally take the mean of the deviances
dev.mean <- mean(deviances)
```